# MASM Comparison/Repetition of Program

Tags: assembly, combinations, masm, irvine32

My code gives the users two numbers and they are supposed to guess the amount of combinations that can be made. Currently, the program always tells the user they are getting the right answer. Also when I ask if they want to play again the program crashes.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

  ;MACRO FOR writeString
my_write_string MACRO buffer
push edx
mov edx, OFFSET buffer
call WriteString
pop edx

ENDM

; (insert constant definitions here)
MAX_SIZE=15
YES='Y'
NO='N'


.data
prompt_title BYTE "Welcome to the Combinations Calculator by Rachael Philpott.", 0
prompt_description BYTE "I'll give you a combinations problem.  You enter your answer, and I'll let you know if you're right", 0     
prompt_1 BYTE "Problem: ", 0          
prompt_2 BYTE "Number of elements in the set: ", 0  
prompt_3 BYTE "Number of elements to choose from the set: ", 0  
prompt_4 BYTE "How many ways can you choose?: ", 0
result_1 BYTE "There are : ", 0 
result_2 BYTE " combinations of ", 0
result_3 BYTE " items from a set of ", 0
result_4 BYTE "Good job!", 0
result_5 BYTE "You need more practice!", 0 
error_msg BYTE "Invalid response!", 0
play_msg BYTE "Do you want to play again? (Y/N): ", 0
goodbye_1 BYTE "Thank you for playing Combinations Calculator! Goodbye!", 0
user_str BYTE MAX_SIZE DUP (?)
str_len DWORD ?                        
n_rand DWORD ?
r_rand DWORD ?
combos DWORD ?
play_again DWORD ?
n_lo DWORD 3
n_hi DWORD 12
r_lo DWORD 1
r_hi DWORD ?
count DWORD ?
ans DWORD ?
divisor DWORD ? 
user_num DWORD ?

; (insert variable definitions here)

.code
main PROC

   call Randomize   
   call introduction
   call showProblem

;Get and validate user input
   push OFFSET user_str
   push MAX_SIZE
   call getData

;Get combinations
   push OFFSET divisor
   push n_rand
   push r_rand
   push OFFSET combos
   call combinations

;Show results
   call showResults

;Say goodbye
   push YES
   call goodbye

;exit to operating system
   exit

main ENDP

;INTRODUCTION
introduction PROC 
      ;display title
      my_write_string prompt_title
      call Crlf
      call Crlf

      ;Print the description of program
      my_write_string prompt_description
      call Crlf
      call Crlf
      ret

introduction ENDP

;SHOW PROBLEM
showProblem PROC 
   ;get random number for n
      nRand:
      mov eax, n_hi
      sub eax, n_lo
      inc eax
      call RandomRange
      add eax, n_lo
      mov n_rand, eax

   rRand:
      mov eax, n_rand
      sub eax, r_lo
      inc eax
      call RandomRange
      add eax, r_lo
      mov r_rand, eax

   displayProblem:
      my_write_string prompt_1
      call Crlf
      my_write_string prompt_2
      mov eax, n_rand
      call WriteDec
      call Crlf

      my_write_string prompt_3
      mov eax, r_rand
      call WriteDec
      call Crlf

      ret

showProblem ENDP

;GET DATA
getData PROC       
   push ebp
   mov ebp,esp
   mov edx,[ebp+12]
   mov ecx, [ebp+8]

   user_input:
      my_write_string prompt_4
      call ReadString
      call Crlf
      mov esi, edx
      mov str_len, eax
      cmp eax, 3
      ja to_large
      cld

  validate:
      lodsb
      cmp al, 48
      jb out_of_range
      cmp al, 57
      ja out_of_range
      jmp done

   to_large:
      my_write_string error_msg
      call Crlf
      call Crlf
      jmp again

   out_of_range:
      my_write_string error_msg
      call Crlf
      call Crlf
      jmp again

   again:
      my_write_string prompt_1
      call Crlf
      my_write_string prompt_2
      mov eax, n_rand
      call WriteDec
      call Crlf

      my_write_string prompt_3
      mov eax, r_rand
      call WriteDec
      Call Crlf
      jmp user_input



   done:
      pop ebp
      ret 8


getData ENDP

;COMBINATIONS
combinations    PROC
   push        ebp
   mov     ebp,esp

   mov     eax, [ebp+16]   
   sub     eax, [ebp+12]
   mov     ebx, eax
   push        ebx
   call        factorial

   mov     edx,[ebp+20]    
   mov     [edx],eax

   mov     ebx, [ebp+12]        
   push        ebx
   call        factorial

   mov     edx,[ebp+20]
   mov     ebx, [edx]
   mul     ebx         
   mov     ebx, [ebp+20]
   mov     [ebx], eax          

   mov     ebx, [ebp+16]   
   push        ebx
   call        factorial

   mov     edx,[ebp+20]            
   mov     ebx,[edx]         

   mov     edx, 0
   div     ebx         
   mov     ebx, [ebp+8]
   mov     [ebx],eax                 

   pop     ebp
   ret     16

combinations    ENDP

;FACTORIAL
factorial   PROC
   mov eax,dword ptr [esp+4]
   cmp eax,1
   jle end_recursive
   dec eax
   push eax
   call factorial
   mov esi,dword ptr [esp+4]
   mul esi

   end_recursive:

      ret 4

factorial   ENDP

;SHOW RESULTS
showResults PROC
   my_write_string result_1
   mov eax, combos
   call WriteDec
   my_write_string result_2
   mov eax, r_rand
   call WriteDec
   my_write_string result_3
   mov eax, n_rand
   call WriteDec
   call Crlf

   ;TRYING TO TELL USER IF GOOD JOB OR IF NEED TO PRACTICE - NOT WORKING CORRECTLY
   ;ALWAYS JUMPS TO DONE AND SAYS GOOD JOB
   mov eax, combos
   cmp eax, edx
   jl wrong_guess
   cmp eax, edx
   jg wrong_guess
   cmp eax, edx
   je done

   wrong_guess:
      my_write_string result_4
      call Crlf
      ret

   done:
      my_write_string result_5
      call Crlf
      ret

showResults ENDP

;GOODBYE/PLAY_AGAIN
    goodbye PROC

   ;TRYING TO DO PLAY AGAIN - CAN'T GET IT TO WORK
  my_write_string play_msg
   call ReadString
   mov esi, edx
   mov ebp, eax
   cmp eax, edx
   je go_again
  jmp done

   go_again:
      call showProblem
   done:

      my_write_string goodbye_1
      call Crlf
      ret
goodbye ENDP

; (insert additional procedures here)

END main
```

Comment: Please be more specific on the problem you encounter, e.g. post an error message/description.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors with the program.. I'm just not getting the right answer.  Here are the two specific spots of code that I am having problems with.  In show results every user guess is shown as correct even if its wrong.  Here's the code I'm talking about `;always says good job
   mov eax, combos
   cmp eax, edx
   jl wrong_guess
   cmp eax, edx
   jg wrong_guess
   cmp eax, edx
   je done

   wrong_guess:
      my_write_string result_4
      call Crlf
      ret

   done:
      my_write_string result_5
      call Crlf
      ret`

Comment: The other part is when trying to repeat or exit the problem.  Which is this part of the code 
`;GOODBYE/PLAY_AGAIN
    goodbye PROC

   ;TRYING TO DO PLAY AGAIN - CAN'T GET IT TO WORK
  my_write_string play_msg
   call ReadString
   mov esi, edx
   mov ebp, eax
   cmp eax, edx
   je go_again
  jmp done

   go_again:
      call showProblem
   done:

      my_write_string goodbye_1
      call Crlf
      ret
goodbye ENDP`